# How to get the CPU micro-architecture name on virtual machines running in the cloud?

Tags: cloud, central-processing-unit, digital-ocean

I have some servers (VMs) running on Digital Ocean, and I'm looking to retrieve the name of the CPU architecture, I know it's Intel but I guess that the information is not easily available. Here is what I get when I run the `lscpu` utility:

```
Architecture:                    x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):                  32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:                      Little Endian
Address sizes:                   40 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
CPU(s):                          4
On-line CPU(s) list:             0-3
Thread(s) per core:              1
Core(s) per socket:              4
Socket(s):                       1
NUMA node(s):                    1
Vendor ID:                       GenuineIntel
CPU family:                      6
Model:                           63
Model name:                      DO-Regular
Stepping:                        2
CPU MHz:                         2294.608
BogoMIPS:                        4589.21
Virtualization:                  VT-x
Hypervisor vendor:               KVM
Virtualization type:             full
L1d cache:                       128 KiB
L1i cache:                       128 KiB
L2 cache:                        16 MiB
NUMA node0 CPU(s):               0-3
```

Is there any information here that can help me get the CPU micro-architecture name (such as Sky Lake, Haswell, etc)? If there is no way, is there a method to infer it based on these information ?

Comment: The only way to archive this, is that you have to ask your vendor. I think the Provider does just hide the original CPU from its customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/cpuid : Family 6 model 63 appears to be Haswell, big core, server. But since it is virtualized, I'm not sure how much you can trust that.